# How to prevent a for loop from erasing it's output every time the loop restarts?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

**Background**: I am creating a tweet scraper, using snscrape, to scrape tweets from sitting government representatives in the House and Senate. The tweets that I'm scraping I am scanning for keywords related to "cybersecurity" and "privacy". I'm using a dictionary of words to scan for. Usually, I would have many more members in the username list but I am just trying to test with a low number to get it working first.

**The problem**: I have set up nested for loops to run through each username to check and the dictionary of words to scan for. The output is only showing the last person in my username list. I can't find out why. It's like every time the for loop restarts it erases the last person it just checked.

**The code**:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

tweet_count = 500
username = ["SenShelby", "Ttuberville", "SenDanSullivan"]
text_query = ["cybersecurity", "cyber security", "internet privacy", "online privacy", "computer security", "health privacy", "privacy", "security breach", "firewall", "data"]
since_date = "2016-01-01"
until_date = "2021-10-14"

for person in username:
  for word in text_query:
      os.system("snscrape --jsonl --progress --max-results {} --since {} twitter-search '{} from:{} until:{}'> user-tweets.json".format(tweet_count, since_date, word, person, until_date))

tweets_framework = pd.read_json('user-tweets.json', lines=True)
tweets_framework.to_csv('user-tweets.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

first you should have a unique name for each user's JSON.

second, you need to run the json to csv for each user (if this is what you try to do)

```py
for person in username:
  for word in text_query:
      filename = '{}-{}-tweets'.format(person, word)
      os.system("snscrape --jsonl --progress --max-results {} --since {} twitter-search '{} from:{} until:{}'> {}.json".format(tweet_count, since_date, word, person, until_date, filename))

      tweets_framework = pd.read_json('{}.json'.format(filename), lines=True)
      tweets_framework.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(filename), sep=',', index=False)
```